# 20.04 Synaptics package manager not supported

Tags: 20.04, synaptic

Installing from [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/synaptic/0.84.6ubuntu5](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/synaptic/0.84.6ubuntu5%C2%A0)  should work, doesn't  Nothing else does.

Failed to install  - file not supported

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

Comment: Synaptic Package manager can be installed simply with `sudo apt install synaptic`.

Comment: "doesn't" is insufficient detail to help you. Your question should contain complete input and output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) . See https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/synaptic , add *universe* by `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and retry.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the respository fixed it.

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

worked

Remember there is a synaptics trackpad and a synaptic package manager.